# slither not working

Tags: solidity, slither

I am running slither's docker image to check my solidity contracts and I keep having the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 744,         in main_impl
) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 87, in process_all
) = process_single(compilation, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 70, in process_single
slither = Slither(target, ast_format=ast, **vars(args))
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/slither.py", line 95, in __init__
parser.parse_top_level_from_loaded_json(ast, path)
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/solc_parsing/slither_compilation_unit_solc.py", line 211, in parse_top_level_from_loaded_json
contract.set_offset(top_level_data["src"], self._compilation_unit)
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/core/source_mapping/source_mapping.py", line 124, in set_offset
self._source_mapping = self._convert_source_mapping(offset, compilation_unit)
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/core/source_mapping/source_mapping.py", line 102, in _convert_source_mapping
compilation_unit, filename, s, l
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slither/core/source_mapping/source_mapping.py", line 44, in _compute_line
filename, start + length
File "/home/ethsec/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 291, in get_line_from_offset
return lines_delimiters[offset]
```

What bothers me is that the smart contracts are ok because I am able to compile and deploy them (and once deployed they seem to work as expected).

For whatever reason slither is not able to analyze them.....